# checking user input submitted via ajax method

Tags: c#, .net, validation

Iv'e created a generic handler (.ashx) to handle some simple input from some dropdowns in a html page.  I know I should check the data to make sure it's valid and so I created the following code

```
string ProjectNumber = context.Request.Form["JobNumber"];
string ProjectShare = context.Request.Form["ProjectShare"];

if (ProjectNumber == null || ProjectNumber == string.Empty) {
     throw new Exception("Project number cannot be empty or null");
}

if (ProjectShare == null || ProjectShare == string.Empty) {
      throw new Exception("Project Share cannot be empty or null");
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `System.String.IsNullOrEmpty()` method and ensure you have client side/js validation that executes before passing the data to the handler.

Answer (score 0):

You should enforce more validation rules on the input values, (not only just 'Empty/null' string check). It depends on the uses of the values. Some basic validations are like *Data-Type, Data-Range, Format* etc. checking. You may define separate validation class for validating user inputs so that you can re-use the validation code in other places; e.g.:

```
public class DataValidator
{
    public ValidationResult ValidateProjectNumber(string projectNumber)
    {
        //ProjectNumber validation rules...
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(projectNumber))
            return new ValidationResult("Project number is requried.");

        int projectId;//say your project number is int.
        if (int.TryParse(projectNumber, out projectId))
            return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Project Number '{0}' is not a valid number."));

        // more checks....

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public ValidationResult ValidateProjectShare(string projectShare)
    {
        //projectShare validation rules...

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

I also suggest, not to throw exceptions for invalid inputs. Instead send validation-results as JSON/xml to the client-side and display the error messages in an user-friendly way.